# django response without client request

Tags: javascript, html, django, browser, httprequest

in normal situation all of http responses occurs after client requests. is it possible having a response and have browser reaction without client request? for example in whats-app web client logout in browser occurs immediately after android app command "Logout all devices".

Answer (score 0):

You should look at [Django Channels](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), it's a convinient way to push data to browser.